# Regex matching different patterns

Tags: r, regex

I have this string

```
mys<-c("16_0-FA", "16_1-FA", "18_2-FA", "18_3-FA", "20_0-FA", "20_4-FA", 
       "16_0-GG", "16_1-GG", "18_2-GG", "18_3-GG", "20_0-GG", "20_4-GG",)
```

I want to subset different patterns. The first is the letters after `-`

```
sub('.*-', '', mys)
```

The second is a specific number between `_` and `-`

`>2` or `==1`

```
mys[as.numeric(gsub(".*_|-.*", "", mys))>2]
```

Now I want to combine and do it simultaneously, I tried this approach but does not work.

```
sub('.*-'| mys[as.numeric(gsub(".*_|-.*", "", mys))>2], '', mys)
```

Outcome should be

```
"18_3-FA" "20_4-FA"
```

Comment: what is your desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the subset of elements for which the second component > 2 and the third equals `FA`, say, then create a 3 column data frame `d` with the 3 components of each `mys` element and then create a logical vector `ok` that indicates whether respective components satisfy the two conditions.  Then subset by it.  No packages are used.

```
d <- read.table(text = gsub("[_-]", " ", mys))
ok <- with(d, V2 > 2 & V3 == "FA")
mys[ok]
## [1] "18_3-FA" "20_4-FA"
```

If you want the subset of the rows of `d` instead then after defining `d` it is just:

```
subset(d, V2 > 2 & V3 == "FA")
##   V1 V2 V3
## 4 18  3 FA
## 6 20  4 FA
```